# Error trying to connect from quarkus to keycloak

Tags: quarkus

when starting up a quarkus service (v2.1.1), and trying to connect to a keycloak instance (v15.0.1) I am getting the following exception stack trace:

```
ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile dev): io.quarkus.oidc.common.runtime.OidcEndpointAccessException
    at io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcProviderClient.getJsonWebKeySet(OidcProviderClient.java:75)
    at io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcProviderClient.lambda$getJsonWebKeySet$0(OidcProviderClient.java:54)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualFunction.apply(SlowContextualFunction.java:21)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform$UniOnItemTransformProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransform.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.AsyncResultUni.lambda$subscribe$1(AsyncResultUni.java:35)
    at io.vertx.mutiny.ext.web.client.HttpRequest$10.handle(HttpRequest.java:717)
    at io.vertx.mutiny.ext.web.client.HttpRequest$10.handle(HttpRequest.java:714)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpContext.handleDispatchResponse(HttpContext.java:371)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpContext.execute(HttpContext.java:358)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpContext.next(HttpContext.java:336)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpContext.fire(HttpContext.java:303)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpContext.dispatchResponse(HttpContext.java:265)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpContext.lambda$null$8(HttpContext.java:520)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:59)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$runOnContext$0(EventLoopContext.java:37)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Here are the configs I have put:

```
# OIDC Configuration
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://<HOST>/auth/realms/<REALM_NAME>
quarkus.oidc.client-id=<CLIENT_ID>
# quarkus.oidc.application-type=service
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=<SECRET>
quarkus.oidc.tls.verification=required

# Enable Policy Enforcement
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true
```

Anyone got an idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Hello, based on this line [  at io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcProviderClient.getJsonWebKeySet(OidcProviderClient.java:75)].  I think that quarkus is not able to reach the JWK of your keycloak instance. Can you check if your realm keys are accesible?

Comment: If I make a GET request on the auth-server-url, i get this as a response. So I assume that the keycloak instance is reachable. (Running Quarkus instance from my localhost)

  "realm": "...",
  "public_key": "...",
  "token-service": "https://<HOST>/realms/<REALM>/protocol/openid-connect",
  "account-service": "https://<HOST>/realms/<REALM>/account",
  "tokens-not-before": 0

Comment: Enable logging support lets see if can get some more info use quarkus.log.min-level=DEBUG and 
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.oidc".level=DEBUG

Comment: This trick help figure it out! Will write in Answer below.
Thank you, @karelss 

Comment: You are wellcome @ginccc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a comment above I found this quarkus config here to be helpful:

```
quarkus.log.min-level=DEBUG
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.oidc".level=DEBUG
```

Which gave me this error:

```
Caused by: org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpResponseException: Unexpected response from server: 400 / Bad Request / Response from server: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Bearer-only not allowed"}
```

So clearly, I had misconfigured the client inside keycloak. Too bad the original error message didn't give me that information by default.